# How to deserialize an array object in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

my question is very simple, I have a spring boot controller that recibes a array of objects like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contracts/{id}/milestones", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateContractMilestones(@PathVariable("id") String contractId,
            @DTO(MilestoneUpdateStateDto.class) List<Milestone> milestones,UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder, final HttpServletRequest request) {
}
```

But when I send the following Json object:

```
[{"id":18,"state":"FINALIZED"},{"id":19,"state":"FINALIZED"}]
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
>   `com.espiritware.opusclick.dto.MilestoneUpdateStateDto` out of
>   START_ARRAY token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of
>   `com.espiritware.opusclick.dto.MilestoneUpdateStateDto` out of
>   START_ARRAY token

My question is what should I do from the backend side to be able to receive this object without errors?

Many Thanks!

Comment: could you please specify the full name of `@DTO` annotation?

Comment: There's no `DTO` annotation in spring boot. You are probably using approach described in https://auth0.com/blog/automatically-mapping-dto-to-entity-on-spring-boot-apis/ . In this case you need to adapt `DTOModelMapper` so that it can also work with lists.

Comment: JSON should start with `{` and end with `}`

Comment: @RomanKonoval How can adapt DTOModelMapper to work with lists? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

update your method signature to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contracts/{id}/milestones", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<?> updateContractMilestones(
    @PathVariable("id") String contractId, 
    List<MilestoneUpdateStateDto> milestones,
    ...
)
```

and try with this JSON

```
{
 [
  {"id":18, "state":"FINALIZED"},
  {"id":19, "state":"FINALIZED"}
 ]
}
```

Comment: don't you forget `@RequestBody`?

Comment: i was only trying to pin point the exact area, yes @RequestBody is required. i'll update it